# SVN repo What is difference between http://server/ ... / and svn://server/ .. /

Tags: c++, linux, svn, ubuntu, visualsvn-server

I'm new in Linux world and recently start messing around with ubuntu server. For week or so I was able  to understand the basics  and now  I'm shooting for more difficult tasks like setting up web server, ssh and SVN.

The question is: how to set url to be visible  like `svn://......../....`

I found this and the book http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html perhaps i'm not doing something right:

> svnserve as daemon
>
> The easiest option is to run svnserve as a standalone “daemon” process. Use the -d option for this:
>
> ```
> $ svnserve -d
> $
> # svnserve is now running, listening on port 3690
> ```

When tape this line and restart the service apache2 nothing changes. And I'm not sure is this the way to make it.

Comment: What is your firewall configuration for port 3690?

Comment: Firewall is turned off I thought of this. I'm Still reading to find what frogот and I wonder if reinstall everything and start fresh. Some times work that way.

Comment: I would use a `svn+ssh:` scheme. The difference is the protocol used to communicate between `svn` server and `svn` client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When tape this line and restart the service apache2 nothing changes

Apache in any way **does not related** to handling svn:// protocol

Quote from referenced by you page of SVN Book

> Once we successfully start svnserve as explained previously, it makes
>   **every repository on your system available to the network**. A client
>   **needs** to specify **an absolute path** in the repository URL. For example,
>   if a repository is located at /var/svn/project1, a client would reach
>   it via svn://host.example.com/var/svn/project1.

(Bolded parts is important)